# Is 90% of the use of paired signed-rank Wilcoxon test incorrect due to violated distributional assumption of symmetry, or is it more general?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

Everywhere, including forums - also this one, handbooks of statistical tests discussions, I can read that the paired Wilcoxon test *does require* the assumption of symmetry.

This would mean, that:

1. Most people use it wrong. Because - even if paired data are often less skewed than data in each sample, practically everywhere I can see people using it blindly without checking this very assumption. From statistical journals, textbooks, papers, conferences
2. There is no objective test for this symmetry proposed by practically neither statistical book, software manual, etc. in the context of Wilcoxon. And judging the symmetry by using histograms, boxplots (be careful about multiple modes hidden by boxplots) or QQ plots is subjective and doesn't match the typical formal way of checking assumptions. It doesn't matter whether we accept such informal ways or not, because there are strict sciences, like pharmaceutical, where regulatory agencies strictly demand the formal testing. And... if such test would reject the symmetry, probably it also means that the median differences aren't zero, so..... it made the work of Wilcoxon. Or paired Wilcoxon was test of symmetry (it is, indeed, too).
3. Wikipedia (and R manual follows that) clearly says, what the test actually does, depending on the assessed null hypothesis. And in the most general case there's no assumption on the differences, it's only about the existence of the pseudomedian(!).

The more we restrict the distribution of differences to be symmetric, or even normal, the more it becomes about median difference. But it's not a must-have.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test

Most of the courses in data analysis says: "if the data don't come from the normal distribution, use the non-parametric alternative" calling the paired Wilcoxon. That's why so many people do it. And let's be honest and not do wishful thinking, in certain areas of science data are strongly skewed and multi-modal, not only within each sample, but also pooled and even the differences between them.

That's why the pseudomedian was defined, as the most general measure of location.

But we all know, that the distribution of differences aren't checked routinely. I heard a professor, who claimed, that all those people use the test wrongly, so maybe even 90% all analyses using it are wrong.

How can it be, if the paired Wilcoxon can relax *any* distributional assumption about the differences, provided the pseudomedian exists?

So - is there the *need* for the symmetry of differences, or is it contextual and depends on the hypotheses to test with paired Wilcoxon?

Comment: The assumptions typically apply to the *null hypothesis,* which you are hoping to *disprove.*  What matters is how plausible or useful such a null hypothesis might be in your application. The problem, then, seems to be located in the possibility that the test might yield small p-values even when comparing data from distributions with the same locations, only because of an asymmetry in the distribution of their differences.  Since many (arguably, "most") of the applications are really trying to detect a difference in *distribution,* maybe that's not a problem at all.

Comment: I agree that this is a problem. People ignore the symmetry issue and routinely misinterpret the results. Some textbooks exacerbate the problem by focusing on the normality test, and an associated "flowchart for selecting a testing method," a bad idea in and of itself.